# Bitronix transaction appears to be committing prematurely

Tags: spring-batch, jta, bitronix

We have a spring-batch process that uses the bitronix transaction manager. On the first pass of a particular step, we see the expected commit behavior - data is only committed to the target database when the transaction boundary is reached.

However, on the second and subsequent passes, rows are committed as soon as they are written. That is, they do not wait for the commit point.

We have confirmed that the bitronix commit is only called at the expected points.

Has anyone experienced this behavior before? What kind of bug am I looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Java XA is designed in such a way that connections cannot be reused across transactions. Once the transaction is committed,  the connection property is changed to autocommit=true,  and the connection cannot be used in another transaction until it is returned to the connection pool and retrieved by the XA code again.